# Why doesn't Navigator.pushNamed(context, "route"); work in my flutter-cupertino-app code example?

Tags: flutter, dart

this is my first question and I hope it's readable.
I've created a sample flutter project where I've illustrated the problem specified in my question.
If the code runs on Android the AndroidAppVersion-Object creates a Material App that contains an AndroidHomeScreen-Object with a red Scaffold and a Button with the title "Android". When the user presses the button the AnotherPageView-Object appears that contains an orange Scaffold.
The AnotherPageView-Object is just a sample page.
If the Platform isn't Android an (IOS-)Cupertino-App will be created by the IOSAppVersion-Object that contains an IOSHomeScreen with a green Scaffold with a Button with the title "IOS". Again the user presses the button to create an AnotherPageView-Object.

So here is the Problem:
When I use
`Navigator.pushNamed(context, AnotherPageView.anotherPage);`
The code doesn't work and it gives me the error I've added down below.
However, it works if I use

```
Navigator.push(context,
    CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => AnotherPageView()));
```

but I'd like to know why it doesn't work with the first one.

The code:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  runApp(Platform.isAndroid ? IOSAppVersion() : AndroidAppVersion());
}

class AndroidAppVersion extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      routes: {
        AnotherPageView.anotherPage: (context) {
          return AnotherPageView();
        }
      },
      home: AndroidHomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class AndroidHomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      body: MaterialButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, AnotherPageView.anotherPage);
        },
        child: Center(
          child: Text('Android'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class IOSAppVersion extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoApp(
      home: IOSHomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class IOSHomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      body: CupertinoButton(
        child: Center(child: Text('Hallo IOS')),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, AnotherPageView.anotherPage);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AnotherPageView extends StatelessWidget {
  static String anotherPage = "anotherPage";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
    );
  }
}
```

Here's the error that gets shown:

> The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
> Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("anotherPage", null) in the _WidgetsAppState.
> Generators for routes are searched for in the following order:
>
> 1. For the "/" route, the "home" property, if non-null, is used.
> 2. Otherwise, the "routes" table is used, if it has an entry for the route.
> 3. Otherwise, onGenerateRoute is called. It should return a non-null value for any valid route not handled by "home" and "routes".
> 4. Finally if all else fails onUnknownRoute is called.
>    Unfortunately, onUnknownRoute was not set.

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
return CupertinoApp(
  home: IOSHomeScreen(),
);
```

doesn't know any routes, you need to provide your routes to both materialapp and cupertinoapp, just do

```
return CupertinoApp(
      routes: {
        AnotherPageView.anotherPage: (context) {
          return AnotherPageView();
        }
      },
      home: IOSHomeScreen(),
    );
```